# Props are undefined in hoisted renderInput function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a functional SearchBar child component that is linked to the parent homepage. I pass it props of id and label from the parent component. The child component reads the props id and label as "undefined." I have this exact same code for another dropdown component and it works. My guess is that this may be because I am passing the props to a hoisted (above the functional component body) renderInput function? Can you pass props to a hoisted helper function? I am also using Redux Form, which I'm not sure if it complicates things. Input, which is a prop from Redux Form, works fine. This is my code:

```
//helper render function hoisted to prevent re-render of searchbar with every key stroke
const renderInput = ({ id, label input }) => {
  return (
    <div className="container position-relative" id={id}>
      {label}

      <input
        {...input}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search..."
        className="py-4 px-5 border rounded-sm form-control"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const SearchBar = ({ handleSubmit, submitSearch }) => {
    
    const onSubmit = (formValues, dispatch) => {
        submitSearch(formValues); //calls search action creator
        dispatch(reset("SearchBar")); //clears search form after submission 
    }
    
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Field
          name="search"
          component={renderInput}
        />
      </form>
    ); 
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass props other then `input` and `meta` which are defined in the Redux Form (see [docs](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/docs/api/field.md/#props)). But you can specify from where do you get `id` and `label`, so maybe we can come up with a solution.

Comment: Hi @rostyslav! Thank you, this might be the problem. The id & label props are coming from the SearchBar parent (I’m defining and creating them, just like you would in a normal React component: <SearchBar id=“search” />). Can I not pass self created React props to a Redux From component? How do I do this? Thanks so much, was stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Your search bar seem to decompose only two params from props `const SearchBar = ({ handleSubmit, submitSearch }) `. id and label are not decomposed. It should be const SearchBar = ({ id, label, handleSubmit, submitSearch })

Comment: But still I guess some code is missing from your example

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I figured it out. I had to pass custom props of id and label to the <Field /> component in Redux Form. That's what was missing. I will post my working code in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code, if anyone else runs into the same issue. You have to pass the custom props of id and label to the Field component in Redux Form for the Redux Form component to read it.

```
<Field name="search" component={renderInput} id={id} label={label} />
```